# Which line number package can cooperate with git gutter in emacs

Tags: git, emacs, line-numbers

I used `linum-mode` to show the line number in emacs. Thing changed, however, after I started using `git-gutter+`. The official doc of `git-gutter+` says that `git-gutter+` can not cooperate with `linum-mode`.

I think now have two choices: 1) give up `linum-mode`, 2) give up `git-gutter+`. I feel OK no matter which one is replaced as long as these two function works properly.

Show me some hints. Thx.

---

Actually, I run emacs in terminal with `-nw` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `diff-hl` (available in your friendly GNU ELPA archive) works fine with both `nlinum-mode` and `linum-mode`, except when they both use the same margin (so you'll want to set diff-hl to either not use the margin, or to use the other margin).

Comment: Does it support emacs that run in a text terminal?

Answer (score 1):

[`git-gutter-fringe-plus`](https://github.com/nonsequitur/git-gutter-fringe-plus) works with `linum-mode`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if you run Emacs in a terminal, but if you run Emacs graphically it should be a good solution.

Comment: Sorry, I do run emacs in a terminal, that why I choice `git-gutter` instead `git-gutter-fringe-plus`...